# Are data objects persistent in openCPU's R session?

Tags: r, opencpu

I would like to provide a web tool that requires access to a large dataset. Preferentially, this R data object should be loaded into memory once and then be available for user-defined queries.

Does the openCPU framework support persistant data objects in any way or does every query begin with a blank slate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The OpenCPU API is stateless, there is no way to keep a process alive in between requests. But you can easily solve your problem by putting your dataset into a package, and installing that on the server.

You can use the `preload` option described in the [server manual](http://jeroenooms.github.com/opencpu-manual/opencpu-server.pdf), or use the `/etc/opencpu/Rprofile` script to load the package with the dataset in memory when the server starts. That way the data will be will be ready to use when requests come in.

Comment: Great ! Thanks a lot for the quick reply. I am working with genomics datasets, but (up to now) it can be loaded into memory. Caching the data will thus probably work for my application.

Comment: A pretty simple way to handle sessions is to save user data in a database like mysql (or sqlite for smaller websites), along with a unique id. Then, after one preloads the relevant database packages in R/opencpu, each new function call will need to look at the cookies and/or request to find the session ID. One might also include some more security, such as adding a timestamp that expires, using cookies instead of url string identifiers, oauth, etc..

Comment: @Jeroen Is your answer still valid with the latest opencpu release ? If not, whats the best practice to query in memory big dataframes through a restful webservice ?

Comment: Thanks @Jeroen ! Any plans in the future to make this available without writing a R package ? I have it captured here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26025430/is-there-a-way-to-run-a-script-through-opencpu-without-creating-a-package

Comment: @AjinkyaKale there is no need to be scared of R packages. It's just the  natural format to combine some functions, data, files, scripts into an easily maintainable and deployable container. You can make an R package in less than 10 seconds. Have a look at this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=kAfVWxiZ-Cc#t=858 around 14m.