# How does caching work in openCPU?

Tags: opencpu

This question is directed towards Jeroen and is a follow-up to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12482918/177984

Jeroen wrote "the server does caching" .. "so if enough memory is available it will automatically be available from memory."

How can I confirm if an object is cached 'in-memory' or not?  From what I can tell (by performance) all of my objects are being read from disk.  I'd like to have things read from memory to speed up data load times.  Is there a way to view what's in the in-memory cache?  Is there a way to force caching objects in-memory?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OpenCPU project is rapidly evolving. Things have changed in OpenCPU 1.0. Have a look at the website for the latest information: http://www.opencpu.org.

The answer that you cited is outdated. Currently indeed all the caching is done on disk. In a previous version, OpenCPU used [Varnish](https://www.varnish-cache.org/) to do caching, which is completely in-memory. However this turned out to make things more complicated (especially https), and performance was a bit disappointing (especially in comparison with fast disks these days). So now we're back at nginx which caches on disk, but is much more mature and configurable as a web server, and has other performance benefits.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Looking forward to the re-implmentation!  What is the timing of that? Follow-up question: what is the lifecycle of objects stored in /R/tmp?  The 'tmp' part implies it is temporary and therefore limited.  But is there anything cleaning up these objects?  Can I rely on them being there forever?

Comment: It's almost ready, need to start documenting. https://github.com/jeroenooms/opencpu for the single-user server and https://github.com/jeroenooms/opencpu-deb#README for the cloud server.