# Is there a way to run a script through Opencpu without creating a package?

Tags: r, opencpu

I am new to opencpu and I am trying this :

1. Create a script to load dataframe in memory (on server of course)
2. Give a method to query this dataframe through GET api.

Can this be done for a large dataframe to keep it loaded once? And can this be done without writing a R package (which is the only way I have found so far to access R scripts through opencpu)

Comment: This was answered here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468574/are-data-objects-persistent-in-opencpus-r-session/12482918?noredirect=1#comment40780945_12482918